# How do you use test-unit?

Tags: ruby, testunit

My `test/run_test.rb` is exactly as the docs have it [here](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/blob/master/doc/text/how-to.md). My `test/spec.rb` has simply `puts 'hello'`, yet running `ruby test/run_test.rb` outputs nothing at all.

I can't find any other documentation on test-unit.

Comment: Try renaming `test/spec.rb` to `test/foo_test.rb`.  I think it needs to end with `_test.rb`.

Comment: It runs inside the folder but doesn't load the test-unit, try copying it 1 folder back.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Thank you. The `*_test.rb` filename got it running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `test/spec.rb` to `test/foo_test.rb`, as your test files need to end with `_test.rb`.

Comment: now you know and don't have to try/think anymore don't you? ;)

Comment: Why the downvote?  My comment turned out to be the right answer so I posted it as an answer.  Please upvote.  If you are @luther, please upvote and mark as the answer.

Comment: @TheCha͢mp: I have to agree with DavidGrayson. The filename thing is a very specific and undocumented requirement. It's not reasonable to expect people to guess the correct answer.

Comment: I'd suggest you rephrase the sentence to bring across assurance. You don't have to *think* it needs to end with `_test.rb`, you should *know* by now. Something like: "Rename x to y, as it needs to end with z"

Comment: Now I understand. I misunderstood your first comment to be sarcasm towards my OP. My bad.